# Illustrator clipping masks containing images and text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask

My clipping mask was working in when it was just text. I have added an image to the text and the clipping mask no longer works even if I group the text and the image. Any ideas?

I was working in Illustrator but could do in Photoshop too - whatever works!

Answer (score 2):

I'm creat mini tut for you. Hope, it will resolve your problem.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clipping masks must be either paths or compound paths. They can not contain raster images.

You'll need to explain far more about what you are after before any further suggestions could be made.

Comment: Maybe it needs to be on the same layer as well with the image below the mask in the Layers Panel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a little lost by your question. I'm not sure what you mean by "added an image to the text".

Select your clipped group then find it in the layers panel. Expand the group in the panel and inspect it's contents: Your problem may be the result of nested groups. Anything that should be clipped should be in the immediate group that contains the clipping path.